# Samba creation help

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

Im going to keep this quick and simple. I made a samba server and it works like a charm. I mounted my 1tb drive on /files and directed the smb.conf to the path. now what i want is to make my foler (Amir's Files) and my dads folder (Hossein's Files) password protected but i want the public folder with no password. Right now all of them need the samba password i made for the samba account. also i need help making my local ip static

Here's the end of smb.conf file

```
[Amir's Files]
 comment = Amir's Files
 path = /files/Amir
 browseable = yes
 read only = no

[Public Files]
 comment = Public Files
 path = /files/open
 browseable = yes
 read only = no

[Hossein's Files]
 comment = Hossein's Files
 path = /files/Hossein
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires authentication:

```
[Public Files]
 comment = Public Files
 path = /files/open
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
```

This does not:

```
[Public Files]
 comment = Public Files
 path = /files/open
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
 guest ok = Yes
```

Comment: Thank You. That solved one problem. Now how do i set passwords for each folder. they all require the one samba password.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The other shares are password protected.

Comment: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-add-or-delete-a-samba-user-under-linux/ Nvm i found the answer. What i meant was to have different passwords for each share. Now i have this other problem which windows dosn't let me connect to all the shares on one computer with the different users created

Comment: Windows only allows one user to connect to smb shares per server unless you use "Map Network Drive" with the "Connect using different credentials" option. Just right click the share in Explorer and select Map Network Drive

Comment: i have tried that with diffrent credentials option and it tells me this https://ibb.co/b8y6Kz  i already have one of the shares connected and im trying to connect the other 2

Comment: I just figured out a workaround that could work. i could just add my user to all the shares and have them all in my pc then make another folder for sharing between users and allow all the users to access it. Thanks @Morbis1